# How to add Hyperlinks in Database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a Textarea box which onSubmit sends data to the database. I may have hyperlinks in some inputs and when I load the data, I want the link to show up as a hyperlink instead of regular text.

I figured I would try using strpos to try and find all instances of HTTP but then using trim and maybe even explode would become too messy.

```
if (strpos($data[$i], 'http:') !== false) { }
```

I know I can just add `<a href="link.html">Link</a>` in my text area and when it gets pulled out of the database, it will act as a link. However, there is a problem with this, if I want to edit this data again, it adds slashes next to the link `<a href="\link.html\">Link</a>`.. The link still works but its just extra characters in the database that I don't need. If I edit about 10 times, its going to add 20 slashes to the database.

Any help or assistance to help me get on the right track will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about strip off the slashes?

Comment: research for `magic quotes` and look into `stripslashes`

Comment: Thanks @EricJ., just what I was looking for.. Can't believe googling for an hour didn't help me find that solution... @

Answer (score 0):

At some point between your app and the database, you are escaping the string being sent in. When the data gets pulled out of the database, try using [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on it.